# How to use mkfs -t ext4 to keep data on existing volume but delete on new?

Tags: bash, shell, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am attaching block volume in OCI to a new or existing instance using a script (below). However, if the volume already has a file system type already assigned I will lose all my data!

Is there a way only to run the command `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/oracleoci/oraclevdb` only if it's not already formatted?

Is there a way to run line 1 below, **only** if the attached volume is not already formatted?

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/oracleoci/oraclevdb
sudo mkdir /data
sudo mount /dev/oracleoci/oraclevdd /data
df -h
```

The issue is every time a new instance is created using an existing volume, I lose all my data. However, I want to keep the behaviour for new instances were attaching a new volume.

So something like...

```
if condition x
   sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/oracleoci/oraclevdb
else
 do nothing
```

I'm running Oracle Linux 8.

Comment: this should be on [su] or [unix.se]

Answer (score 1):

Just check if you can mount it.

```
if ! sudo mount /dev/oracleoci/oraclevdd /data; then
     if ! sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/oracleoci/oraclevdb; then
          echo "och nooo, formatting fialed"
     fi
     if ! sudo mount /dev/oracleoci/oraclevdd /data; then
          echo "Och nooooo, can't mount after formatting, that's odd"
     fi
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this info running `lsblk` like so:

```
lsblk  -o NAME,FSTYPE
```

and run a test using some script:

```
export DEVICE="/dev/oracleoci/oraclevdb"
export FSTYPE="ext4"

if ! lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE | grep $DEVICE | grep $FSTYPE; then
    sudo mkfs -t $FSTYPE $DEVICE
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You could use `file` to check for content of *anything*:

with option:

> ```
> -b, --brief
>     Do not prepend filenames to output lines (brief mode).
> -L, --dereference
>     option causes symlinks to be followed, as the like-named option in ls
> -s, --special-files
>     Specifying the -s option causes file to also read argument files which
>     are block or character special files.
> ```

Create a script `conditionalMkExt4`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -b $1 ]] ;then
    echo "Not a block device: '$1'"
    exit 1
fi
sudo /bin/bash <<eof
```

```bash
    read -r partTyp < <(file -Lsb "$1")
    case \$partTyp in
        data ) 
            mkfs -t ext4 "$1"
            ;;
        * )
            echo "Device '$1' is of type: '\$partTyp'"
            exit 1
            ;;
    esac
    if [[ $2 ]] ;then
        [[ -e $2 ]] || mkdir -p "$2"
        mount "$1" "$2"
    fi
```

```bash
eof
```

Then

```
conditionalMkExt4 /dev/oracleoci/oraclevdb /data
```

#### If you want to be able to whipe any *non ext4* partition:

Juste replace `case ... esac` by

```
    case \$partTyp in
        *ext4* ) 
            echo "Device '$1' already formated as ext4"
            exit 1  # Comment this if you want to mount if already formated
            ;;
        * )
            mkfs -t ext4 "$1"
            ;;
    esac
```